# Adding servers to a service

Tags: background, worker

I'm building an architecture in that web servers dispatches jobs to background worker nodes in a random way so the load is balanced.

How could my web servers know that I've added a worker node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They could just say “Hi, I'm here and work for food” by connecting to a special URI on your web servers.